# Why JavaScript doesn't allow both incrementing and setting value same time like C?

Tags: javascript

In C If we try to do this:
(do not mind the example, it's just here to show the idea but not intended to be logical or a useful use case)

```c
   char* buf = calloc(5, 1);
   unsigned char buf_i = 0;
   memcpy(buf, "test", 4);
   /* buf_i++  0, ++buf_i  1 */
   buf[buf_i++] = 'e';
   /* expected eest, result eest */
   puts(buf);
```

In js if we try to do that:

```js
   let text = "test"
   let text_i = 0
   text[text_i++] = 'e';
   console.log(text)

   // expected eest, result is test
```

Question is why this wouldn't work and why such behaviour cannot be expected from JS?

Comment: Because strings in Javascript are not mutable

Comment: It's not clear why JS even lets you write `text[text_i++] = 'e'` in the first place without giving you an error.  But strings cannot be modified.

Comment: This has nothing to do with incrementing, `text[0] = 'e'` will also fail to change `text`

Comment: would it be good idea to turn string into an array in js and modify it then convert it back to a string to bypass this annoyance? and why doesn't such code give a error

Comment: You can, and feel free to to do that, but it is not an annoyance, it is a feature. Knowing that strings can't mutate also has its benefits.

Comment: @FrankYellin This throws in strict mode.